# Why JSF tomahawk dataTable do not show?

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, tomahawk

I am trying to create the world most simple dataTable using JSF tomahawk like this:

```
<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">
<h:head>
  <title></title>
</h:head>
  <h:body>
    <h:form id="theForm">
      <h:outputText value="#{theBean.theList eq null}"/>
        <t:dataTable id="dt1" value="#{theBean.theList}" var="item">
          <t:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
              <t:outputText value="Header A"/>
            </f:facet>
            <t:outputText value="#{item.itemA}"/>
          </t:column>
        </t:dataTable>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

The above code was save as XHTML file. The bean class is look like this:

```
@ManagedBean(name="theBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean {
  private MyData[] theList = new MyData[] {
        new MyData("1111", "", "", "")};

  public MyData[] getTheList() {
    return theList;
  }

  public void setTheList(MyData[] theList) {
    this.theList = theList;
  }
}

public class MyData {

   private String itemA;

   ...
   ...
}
```

In the output of the screen I don't see a data table, I see a black color `false` word and white blank screen, this is due to this code `<h:outputText value="#{theBean.theList eq null}"/>` telling me that the list is not empty.

I see this from the output from the web browser source:

```
<t:dataTable id="dt1" value="[Lcom.foo.MyData;@1798a6c" var="item">
  <t:column>
    <t:outputText value=""></t:outputText>
  </t:column>
</t:dataTable>
```

I am just curious to know why the data table doesn't show? How to make it show on the screen?

Comment: Check the JSF-generated HTML output in the client side (open page in browser, rightclick, *View Source*). Is the `<t:dataTable>` parsed or not?

Comment: What do you mean by parsed or not? If I see or don't see it what does it mean?

Comment: right click on the page in chrome and check the output html using inspect element and see if you can see the datatable with its id

Comment: What do you see in the JSF-generated HTML output? Do you see the `<t:dataTable>` unchanged (unparsed, plain vanilla, unrendered, whatever you call it to indicate that the whole tag didn't do its job at all) instead of its generated HTML `<table>` code?

Comment: Sorry guys, I have update the question by adding the source code from web browser view. I can see the `<dataTable>` but I don't see any output from the column header `Header A` and details `#{item.itemA}`. Am I did anything wrong?

Comment: If your generated HTML contains `<t:...` tags, something must be severely broken with your tomahawk config. I wonder if you don't see any other errors. The `<t:dataTable>` should have become a regular `<table>` - or not been rendered at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for my bad. I didn't include tomahawk jar and other dependencies as well in my classpath. Once I have them inside my classpath, the `dataTable` is rendered on the web page. And I notice that, the warning on the tomahawk line located on top of the page has been gone.

```
<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">
```